# How to check the current UITableView row's document file size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, filesize

I currently have a UITableView showing my app's document directory. How can I get the file size of the current row's document?

My code is currently as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellID";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // layout the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.drive.filesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSInteger iconCount = [docInteractionController.icons count];
    cell.imageView.image = [docInteractionController.icons objectAtIndex:iconCount - 1];

    NSString *fileURLString = [self.drive.filesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fileURLString error:nil];
    NSString *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
    long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",
                                 fileSizeNumber, [self.drive.filesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work though. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a quick note: the value under the `NSFileSize` key is not of type `NSString*` but `NSNumber*` according to the documentation. Not sure, whether this is related to your problem.

Comment: thanks for the tip, although it still doesn't work if I change that :(

Comment: Is there an error being returned from NSFileManager? Have you checked the error is nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what self.drive.filesArray is, but if you do it with NSDocumentDirectory, get path and then files in that path, it will work.

Here is sample which work for me and I think this is the way how to deal with document directory for application on iOS:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *files = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSString *fileFirst = [files objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, fileFirst];
NSDictionary *attrs = [fm attributesOfItemAtPath:fullPath error:nil];
long long fileSize = [attrs fileSize];

NSLog(@"File is %@ and size is %lld",fileFirst, fileSize)
```

You will end up with something similar like

```
2012-01-28 22:34:00.916 fileOperations[57498:f803] File is smallImage.jpg and size is 30979
```

I think you still have wrong path, mine (on iPhone with iOS 5.0.1) is

```
/var/mobile/Applications/DA47CD6A-8AA8-4739-8CCB-6087F30C0954/Documents/smallImage.jpg
```

point here is **Documents**. Correct your code to get right path, save files to right path and you should be able to get attributes from files. Your file probably doesn't exist or fm just doesn't have rights to get what you want. I don't know, because you send errors from file manager to **nil** object. Also question, how are you collecting **self.drive.filesArray** array?
Try to collect your self.drive.filesArray that way, I wrote above. It works.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how I do it in my project, except that I say `NSString* fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileFirst];`.

Comment: Perfect, that works for me! Only thing is though, will it always be in kilobytes? How can I put the "type" after the number (e.g. "234kb")?

Comment: This size is in bytes. You have to divide it by 1024 to get KB or 1048576 to get MB size.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your code:

```
NSLog(@"fileURLString %@", fileURLString);
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:fileURLString error:nil];
NSLog(@"fileAttributes %@", fileAttributes);
NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
NSLog(@"fileSizeNumber %@", fileSizeNumber);

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", fileSizeNumber, [self.drive.filesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Check if you supply the correct fileURLString to get attributes. To get more information about the structure of iOS Application directory structure it is useful to get familiar with [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2)

Comment: That (whatever it is) cannot be null, object can only be nil. I updated the code for making debugging easier

Comment: So the problem is the fully classified file path, not the filename you provide. All the rest is correct

Comment: I now have the following code: http://pastie.org/3271473 and the following log: http://pastie.org/3271478 - what's gone wrong?

Comment: try to use more error safe methods like:

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"back" ofType:@"png"];

and check the correct file path in your particular case. Note that the file path depends on whether you execute your code - on real device or in device simulator

Comment: that just returns (null) for everything. I'm using my actual iPhone, not the simulator.

Comment: Added link to appropriate documentation resource

Comment: Still don't really understand what I need to do in relation to the code I currently have...